# android fragment setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I use fragment and when i click on an editext an layou is shown whith an special keyboard, (many buttons clickable), but i can't find he correct way to detect the click on buttons

here's the onCreateView code:

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview,container, false);
                try {
                    setKeys();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
                }
        //

        return view;
    }
```

Here's the setKeys code: (i've try many things on mBSpace button)

```
        public void setKeys() {
        mWindowWidth = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); // getting
        // window
        // height
        // getting ids from xml files
        mB[0] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xA);
        mB[1] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xB);
        mB[2] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xC);
        mB[3] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xD);
        mB[4] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xE);
        mB[5] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xF);
        mB[6] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xG);
        mB[7] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xH);
        mB[8] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xI);
        mB[9] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xJ);
        mB[10] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xK);
        mB[11] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xL);
        mB[12] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xM);
        mB[13] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xN);
        mB[14] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xO);
        mB[15] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xP);
        mB[16] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xQ);
        mB[17] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xR);
        mB[18] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS);
        mB[19] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xT);
        mB[20] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xU);
        mB[21] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xV);
        mB[22] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xW);
        mB[23] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xX);
        mB[24] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xY);
        mB[25] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xZ);
        mB[26] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS1);
        mB[27] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS2);
        mB[28] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS3);
        mB[29] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS4);
        mB[30] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS5);
        mB[31] = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xS6);
        mBSpace = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xSpace);
        mBdone = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xDone);
        mBChange = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xChange);
        mBack = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xBack);
        mNum = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xNum);
//      for (int i = 0; i < mB.length; i++)
        mBSpace.setOnClickListener( this);
/*      
        mBSpace.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    edittext_onClick(v );
                }
              });
*/          
/*          
            mB[i].setOnClickListener( this);
        mBSpace.setOnClickListener( this);
        mBdone.setOnClickListener( this);
        mBack.setOnClickListener( this);
        mBChange.setOnClickListener( this);
        mNum.setOnClickListener( this);
//      mNum.setOnClickListener( this);
*/      


    }
```

Does somebody known he correct syntax do to this?
I've try call setkey() into :

```
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setKeys();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I've no error but no click detection too...
Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try android:clickable="true" in the xml elements for EditText?

Comment: the onAcivityCreated running pretty good, buttons are clickable. i've try only the alphabet and in the code only the spacebar has setonclicklistener ..... HeHe When i correct the code, all the keyboard seem to be ok, Thanks,thanks... man thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the special keyboard layout is part of the present contentView. If it is not and you are inflating it into the current view then when you are getting references to the buttons you should use

```
buttonA = inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Also create a common onClickListener and bind all the buttons to it

```
OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                edititext.setText(v.getTag().toString()); 
                // or whatever logic you are using

            }

}
```